# Create IAM user through node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I want to create a new IAM user through the AWS API, anyone know if this is possible?

I can access S3 through various users using node js, however I cant seem to find a way of doing this - the closest I could get was http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/IAM.html where you can `addClientIDToOpenIDConnectProvider` but I cant figure out how to add a whole new user.

Any guidance would be appreciated

Comment: You were so close :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Creates a new IAM user for your AWS account](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/IAM.html#createUser-property)

```
var params = {
  UserName: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  Path: 'STRING_VALUE'
};
iam.createUser(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```